# Почему я не могу использовать message?

Tags: python, telebot

Пытаюсь сделать проверку ключа на валидность
Вот код:

```
def start(message):
    keys = message.text

    

    key = re.sub(r"[/check ]", "", keys)

    print(key)
     
    if key == "test":
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id,  "okay"  ) 

        a = 1

        idi(a)

        

    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id,  "ne okay"  )

        a = 0

        idi(a)

        
    

def idi(a, message):      
    if a == 1:    
    
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id,  "Пожалуйста подождите..."  )
```

Получаю вот такую ошибку:
`TypeError: idi() missing 1 required positional argument: 'message'`

Comment: нужно перевести ошибку на русский язык или что? там все четко написано

Comment: Всё равно регулярка неправильная...

Comment: @Эникейщик, странная она... Я подумал, что вместо 1 аргумента передано 0 и долго думал... Особенно при том, что не сразу заметил функцию в коде.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы описали функцию `idi` с двумя параметрами:

```
def idi(a, message):      
    if a == 1:    
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, \
            "Пожалуйста подождите..."  )

def start(message):
    keys = message.text   
    key = re.sub(r"[/check ]", "", keys)
    print(key)     
    if key == "test":
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id,  "okay"  ) 
        a = 1
        idi( a, '' ) # необходимо передать второй параметр
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id,  "ne okay"  )
        a = 0
        idi( a, '' ) # и тут необходимо передать второй параметр
```

Comment: Ну только пустой строки там и не хватало...

Comment: Я только изучаю питон и надеюсь, что это правильный ответ )

Comment: Идея правильная. Но учитывая, что функция использует `message.chat.id`, message - явно не строка. А судя по наличию такого же `message.chat.id` в вызывающей функции, надо было передавать сам `message`. А ещё у него регулярка неправильная, но это, вроде, не относится к вопросу.

Comment: я понял, 'message' это объект который содержит 'chat' который в свою очередь имеет 'id'. Да, это я написал неправильно.... )